# prepend image to dynamic className jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to prepend image to a div using its `className` in jquery

```
function someFn(obj)
{
    var dynaClass = $(obj).prop("className");
```

This is giving me classname `dia_wrapper_0`.
Now i am wrapping the string with single quotes and `.` to access the class name

```
    dynaClass = "'."+dynaClass+"'";
```

This is giving me `'.dia_wrapper_0'` . Now i'm prepending the image to this class name

```
    $(dynaClass).prepend('<img src="img.png" id="loading-image">');
}
```

My console.log is showing

```
    Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.dia_wrapper_0'
```

How do i prepend image to my dynamic className

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to re-query the element, the element with the class you need is obj so you can do

```
$(obj).prepend('<img src="img.png" id="loading-image">');
```

Getting class names like that is highly inefficient. If you need to do that please consider another approach because your code could easily break if obj has several classes. eg.   would result in dynaClass = '.class-1 class-2' which would also throw errors when pushed back into jquery

Answer (score 2):

The class selector should not be wrapped in `''`, it should be string like `.myclass` not like `'.myclass'`

```
dynaClass = "."+dynaClass;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. Usually if i want to access class in jQuery it should be $('.classname'). Is it correct? and why not in this case?

Comment: Adding '' in your hand coded source creates a string variable. The jQuery you use to get the class name returns a string so jquery knows 'dynaClass' is already a string. By adding the single quotes, you're saying the value of dynaClass is "'.dia_wrapper_0'", as opposed to ".dia_wrapper_0"